# Between in sql query not working if month is change

Tags: sql

I am using Between to get all record from table between two dates an it is working fine if both the dates are from same month but if I change months then it show no rows found

```
SELECT * from user_details WHERE currentdate BETWEEN '14/05/2018' AND '20/05/2018'
```

It will fetch all row between these dates but if I change month then it show no record found

```
SELECT * from user_details WHERE currentdate BETWEEN '30/05/2018' AND '20/06/2018'
```

Comment: Which sql language are you using

Comment: is it possible that there are no entries between those dates?

Comment: please share table data screen shot

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using current date format , you need to define column date format

```
SELECT * from user_details WHERE str_to_date(currentdate, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '30/05/2018' AND '20/06/2018'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe dates are stored as `text`? If yes, temporal workaround is to cast to `DATE` data type.

```
SELECT * 
from user_details
WHERE CAST(currentdate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('30/05/2018' AS DATE)
                                    AND CAST('20/06/2018' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using dates as strings. Need to convert it to date, for example

```
SET @date := 'Jul.20 2018';

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%M.%d %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard date formats:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_details
WHERE currentdate >= '2018-05-14' AND
      currentdate < '2018-05-20';
```

Notice that I also switched from using `BETWEEN`.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a really good blog post by Aaron Bertrand explaining why.  Note that he is talking specifically about SQL Server but most of the discussion applies to any database.